# CakePhp belongsTo input

Tags: cakephp-2.3

Neebe in cakephp trying to set up a simple appoiment system.
My problem is to populate the Pacient Name with only the names of the the pacients belonging to the current log in user.But if I used find('list') I get all the pacients for all the users.

here are the database table in question;

**1 - pacients**

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Doctor_Appointments`.`pacients` (
 `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL ,
 `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
 `user_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL ,
```

**2 - Users**

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Doctor_Appointments`.`users` (
 `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL ,
 `username` VARCHAR(65) NULL ,
 `email` VARCHAR(65) NULL ,
 `password` VARCHAR(65) NULL ,
```

**3 - Appointments**

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Doctor_Appointments`.`appointments` (
`id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL ,
`pacient_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
`date` DATETIME NULL
```

**Pacient Model**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

**Appoiment Model**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Pacient' => array(
        'className' => 'Pacient',
        'foreignKey' => 'pacient_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
```

**Appointments/add.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Appointment'); ?>
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo __('Add Appointment'); ?></legend>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('date');
echo $this->Form->input('pacient_id');
```

The problem must be here at the **AppointmentsController**

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->Appointment->create();
        $this->request->data['appointment']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id'); //Added this line
        if ($this->Appointment->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The appointment has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The appointment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

    $foo =  $this->Auth->user('id');
    $pacients = $this->Appointment->Pacient->findAllByUserId($foo, array('Pacient.name') , array("Pacient.name" => 'desc') );
    pr($pacients);

$doctors  = $this->Appointment->Doctor->find('list');
$this->set(compact('pacients', 'doctors'));

}
```

The pr($pacients) give me too mucha data see it below

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Pacient] => Array
            (
                [name] => samuel Giani
                [id] => 520178db-aa94-40d2-86e9-4fc38e7a58df
            )

        [Appointment] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Pacient] => Array
            (
                [name] => pablo Giani
                [id] => 520178ed-d564-465c-93fd-498f8e7a58df
            )

        [Appointment] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Figuere it out after trying many finds and Pr

```
$pacients =$this->Appointment->Pacient->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array('User_id' => $foo)
    ));
```

I hope it helps another neeby like me